# How do I uninstall an old version of Ruby, and is it a wise thing to do?

Tags: ruby, linux

When logged in as root and I type

```
ruby -v
```

centOS server reports 'ruby 1.9.3p392'. This is what I want.

But if I put

```
rvmsudo ruby -v
```

then I get 'ruby 1.8.7'. I do not want to use this older version, it is causing problems for my gitlab install.

I would like to remove it and make sure only v1.9 is used, how can I do this? Or should I leave it there but try and require certain users to use a different version?

Also, in case doing this messes anything up, is it possible to either;

a.see if anything on the server requires v1.8?

b.reverse the uninstall if it causes a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Before uninstalling, take note of the patch level of 1.8.7 just in case.** `rvmsudo ruby -v` should return something like `ruby 1.8.7p234`. The p#{num} is your patch level.

You should be able to uninstall 1.8.7 with `rvm uninstall 1.8.7` (or possibly `rvmsudo uninstall 1.8.7`). This version of Ruby *shouldn't* be used by anything on the system other than code you've written, so it should only affect your applications and scripts.

The best way to tell what else would be using 1.8.7 is to look for scripts and crontabs that are owned by the user that rvm is running under. I'm not sure there's a tool that can evaluate it for you.

The best way to roll back in case of an emergency is `rvm install 1.8.7-p#{num_from_above}`. Alternatively, if you're on a platform like AWS or have rsync backups enabled, you might consider taking a snapshot that you can roll back to if you get in over your head.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: When I rvm uninstall 1.8.7 I am told /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p374 has already been removed.
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374 has already been removed. Yet still rvmsudo ruby -v reports 1.8.7 Does it need a reboot?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this, but since you accepted the answer, I'm guessing an `rvm reload` or a reboot fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting default

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2

$ ruby -v

#ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

to remove you can use:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby 1.8.7
```

Docs [here](http://rvm.io/rubies/default) & [here](http://rvm.io/rvm/basics)

Comment: I had already done this before I posted. rvmsudo ruby -v still gives me the older version. Can anyone explain the difference between rvmsudo and rvm please?

Comment: RVM sudo switches the user RVM uses to one with admin credentials. Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove ruby 1.8.7`

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the ruby version output for root is `ruby 1.9.3p392` in my understanding you will not have any problems.

Sure, you can have more than one version of ruby installed and find them under `~/.rvm/rubies`. Also there you can find out the default version which is used. For more information you can have a look here: [set default ruby](http://rvm.io/rubies/default)  where it explains how to set a default ruby and how to reset to the systems default.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall cocoapods and install cocapods in the right directory.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```